# Using if statements to change multiple cells in excel

Tags: excel, apache

I am trying to change multiple cells from 0 into either Permanent or Variable.
I cannot get it to work, the cells all contain 0 or 1 in them and i am trying to write an if statement to when 0 or 1 comes up its changes to Permanent if it is 0 and 1 if it is Variable, I can get the code to  work for a single cell but not for multiple cells

```
IF(H101:H106=0; "Permanent" ; "Variable")
```

At the moment it just changes the 1st cell to permanent if it has a 0 or variable if it has a 1 but the rest or the cells are changed to a variable no matter what are in the cells

Comment: Where are you using that formula? You wont be able to change the same cells value without the use of VBA but you could enter the data into the column next to it?

Comment: im using it in apache, i just want to change all the cells in that particular column but dont know how to go about it

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you saying that if a range of cells contains all 0s you want to change the contents of a cell to say "Permanent", and if there is at least one non-zero value, you want to change the contents of a cell to say "Variable"?
Also, what do you mean you're using Apache? That doesn't make sense. Apache is a web server, Excel is a spreadsheet.

Comment: using apache office, very like microsoft excel for spreadsheets but its not. I wanted to write code that if 0 came up in a column it would then turn into "permanent" and if 1 came up it would turn into "variable".